# Import external text file into Xamarin Forms application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, file-io

I need to import a CSV file downloaded to a device into my Xamarin Forms application so that I can read the file contents, convert to Json and load into POCO objects and then send to SQLite database. My only question is how to select the file from the device file system for processing. I have looked at Gerald Versluis FilePicker Plugin for Xamarin and Windows. Is this my only choice for this process or is there something else available that I have not found?

Comment: Does the user need to select the file?  If so, using the file picker plugin would be a good idea, but you could certainly write your own UI to do it.  If you just need to open the file without user action, simply use `System.IO.File`

Comment: Set the file type as `text/comma-separated-values` for the `FilePicker` control (Xamarin.Essentials) to allow only CSV files

Answer (score 0):

Yes the the user needs to select the file from device storage, where ever that might be. The file picker plugin is what I decided to use as the plugin will let you select the file and read it into your app as a stream. Once you have the stream, you can pretty well do what ever you need.